# Trying to make simple UIImageVIew animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I am trying to so a simple UIImageView animation. I have 11 images of .png type. The animation is just a rabbit blinking. I am having issues with the array:

```
UIImageView *animationView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2-123/2, self.view.bounds.size.height/2-278/2, 123, 278)];

    NSArray *imageNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"rabbit-1.png",@"rabbit-2.png",@"rabbit-3.png",@"rabbit-4.png",@"rabbit-5.png",@"rabbit-6.png",@"rabbit-7.png",@"rabbit-8.png",@"rabbit-9.png",@"rabbit-10.png",@"rabbit-11.png", nil];


    NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for(int x =0; x==[imageNames count]; x++){
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: [imageNames objectAtIndex:x]];
        [images addObject:image];
    }

    NSLog(@"image name array length is : %d",[images count]);



    animationView.animationImages=images;
    animationView.animationDuration=10;
    [self.view addSubview:animationView];
    [animationView startAnimating];
```

Nothing is appearing on the screen because the images array is empty. Not sure why this is. I did init and alloc in it but when I check the length it comes back as zero. Any ideas what is going on here? Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x == [imageNames count]` is always false, so the for loop won't get executed.

Change the line

```
for(int x =0; x==[imageNames count]; x++)
```

to

```
for(int x = 0; x < [imageNames count]; x++)
```

Comment: omg, I'm such an idiot. this is what happens when I take a few weeks off coding. thanks

Comment: @KexAri Glad to help. Please accept my answer, it's important to me, thanks.